# Serilog Integration with .net c# class library

Tags: c#, serilog

I am working on an application that was developed using c++ and c#. Main executable will be in c++ and c# dll(functions in the c# dll) will be called using COM interface from c++. However no executable at c# side , every projects are class library. I planned to use serilog framework for c# side logging. I am not able to do that since no main executable is not there at c# side.

In my case whether any possibilities are there to use serilog framework at c# side?

Comment: You can use constructor for instantiate `Log.Logger` in your class library or you can use inheritance for that if you are separating it in a module.

Comment: @Hardik Actually I was tried to initiate Log.Logger in constructor of class library class , it was not succeed. Log.Logger initiate itself failing i was not able to catch the failure.

Comment: Is there any error? have to try to log information just after creating of instance?

Comment: I was initializing Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Console().CreateLogger(); in constructor of a class and i have writing information into file Before and After the above line of code . When i am having the above line of code Both prints are not printed that is before and also after. When i am removing the above line of code both prints are printed .I added above line of code in try catch and in catch also i have added some prints and that is also not printed.

Comment: So, Is it working now?

Comment: No , It was not working.

Comment: Ok, Then you are doing something wrong. Can I have sample code please? or plunkr link please?

Comment: This was the code ,

public class EServerAPI : IEServerAPI
{
 public EServerAPI()
 {
  try
  {
   System.IO.File.WriteAllText("E:\\InitLog.txt", "Going to initialize logger.");
   
   Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Console().CreateLogger();
   
   System.IO.File.WriteAllText("E:\\InitLogEnd.txt", "Initialize logger has end.");
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
   System.IO.File.WriteAllText("E:\\exception.txt",ex.Message);
  }
  catch
  {
   System.IO.File.WriteAllText("E:\\unhandExce.txt","unhandled excpetion occur");
  }
 }
}

Comment: please try this code once.

`Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().CreateLogger();`
`Log.Information("No one listens to me!");`

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

try to create logger only.
and then just next line try to log something.

```
 public class EServerAPI : IEServerAPI
    { 
        public EServerAPI()
        { 
            try
            { 
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText("E:\\InitLog.txt", "Going to initialize logger.");
                Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                                 .WriteTo.File("logs\\myapp.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                                 .CreateLogger();
                Log.Information("Hello, world!");
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText("E:\\InitLogEnd.txt", "Initialize logger has end.");
            }
            catch(Exception ex) 
            { 
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText("E:\\exception.txt",ex.Message); 
            }
            catch 
            { 
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText("E:\\unhandExce.txt","unhandled excpetion occur");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried the above code again the same it was not working .